# Git: ability to stage patch

Tags: git, stage

Follow-up from [Git: ability to stage a certain file content without touching the working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580277/git-ability-to-stage-a-certain-file-content-without-touching-the-working-tree):

I want to modify the index of one (text) file **by staging a patch (against HEAD)** without having to change the working tree file state. Is this possible?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want. You mean you want the index modified but not the working tree? What is the eventual goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `git apply --cached`

From the man page:

```
   --cached
       Apply a patch without touching the working tree. Instead take the cached data, apply the patch, and store
       the result in the index without using the working tree. This implies --index.
```